# Why is InstallShield wizard not displaying last uninstall page?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, installshield, uninstallation

I have a trial version of the InstallSheild. It works perfectly fine on my Windows 7 machine. However uninstalling on other machine it fails to display the Final complete page(The last uninstall page)

To be clear it uninstall correctly but it just fails to show the completed page.

Are the other machine missing a component I need to package with the installer or is this a permissions problem?

Comment: Try creating a verbose log in each scenario and comparing them to see if anything stands out. (Unfortunately you won't be able to just diff the files, as there will be timestamp differences.)

Comment: @MichaelUrman After creating a log and checking it I did not find anything that could be the cause of my problem there.

Comment: What project type are you using?  It's virtually impossible to answer this question without looking at the installer source, build output and/or installer log.  You've barely scratched the surface so it's really pointless to suggest it's the tool and that you need to go scratch the surface of some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

You're question leaves out a few key details:

How are you invoking the uninstall?
What UI are you seeing?
Can we see the contents of your log?

In general, most people uninstall via Add Remove Programs aka Programs and Features.  In this scenario  Windows Installer only displays a progress bar and then exits as the UI sequence is bypassed per best practices.